# Newsletter tab in admin backend disappeared after upgrade from 1.6 to 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, upgrade, newsletter, ce-1.8.1.0

I've recently upgraded a site from 1.6 and I've had some minor issues which I've mostly resolved now. My final hurdle is the newsletter tab which have mysteriously disappeared.

Any idea why it's gone and (even better) any ideas on how to get it back?

Even just suggestions on how to debug this issue would be appreciated.

Update:
I've experimented with creating a new user and giving this user a new role with only access to the Newsletter pages. Once I log in with this user I'm taken to one of the pages I have access to. I have toggled each newsletter page on and off and logged in and out for each to verify that all the pages work; and they do. The menu is still missing which confirms my theory that the update somehow broke the Newsletter menu entries. Any suggestions to how I can make the Newsletter tab (re-)appear?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check `System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Advanced > Modules output > Mage Newsletter` and verify that the output is enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Go to `app/etc` and find `Mage_Newsletter.xml` file. If it is not there open `Mage_All.xml` and find

```
<Mage_Newsletter>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>core</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Core/>
        <Mage_Customer/>
        <Mage_Eav/>
        <Mage_Widget/>
    </depends>
</Mage_Newsletter>
```

If its not there add it. Also check if module Newsletter is present in `app/code/core/Mage`.

**Update 1**

Check if `\app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\etc\adminhtml.xml` is present and if it has some content. All problems that you described could happen if it is missed.

**Update 2**

Go to `System > Configuration > ADVANCED > Advanced > Modules output` and check if it is `enabled`.

Comment: The code you posted was present in Mage_All.xml and the module is present in `app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter`. Any other ideas?

Comment: Could you go to System->Permissions->Roles Roles Resources and check if Newsletter acls are present there.

Comment: The Newsletter acls are present.

Comment: What is the content of `\app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\etc\adminhtml.xml`?

Comment: Here is the content: http://pastie.org/8736376

Comment: Can you please check which role is assigned to your user admin. After set "Resource Access" -> custom and allow all resources for that role. Save role. Logout and than login. What happens?

Comment: I've experimented with creating a new user and giving this user a new role with only access to the Newsletter pages. Once I log in with this user I'm taken to one of the pages I have access to. I have toggled each newsletter page on and off and logged in and out for each to verify that all the pages work; and they do. The menu is still missing which confirms my theory that the update somehow broke the Newsletter menu entries. Any suggestions to how I can make the Newsletter tab appear in the menu?

Comment: Try to disable all local and community extensions to make sure that they do not cause the problem.

Comment: What is the status? Did my advises help you?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions, but they did not help me solve the problem. Core files do not mysteriously change because of an upgrade. Database settings such as Emi suggested often do though.

Comment: @oleksii.svarychevskyi : Your answer has better explanatory than the previous one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: guys see this & help me pls: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194959/how-can-we-connect-with-channel-connect-magentocommerce-com-core-to-upgrade-fr